# How to add a label below the button in the tool bar?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, button, interface-builder, toolbar

I am new to iphone development.I have kept a button in the tool bar.I have given a image for it.I have to give a label to it (below the button).If i placed a label below the button  and give text in the label and while running i am not able to see the text.I don't know where i go wrong.Since i am doing this in interface builder i am not able give code here.Please help me out.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do mean tool-bar and not tab-bar then you are probably falling foul of the "slow double click" needed to edit the settings for a tool bar button.

First click once on your tool bar to select that, then click again on your button. You will see the focus move to the button because it will either get a "halo" (if you double click) or a sizing handle if you single click. Then press cmd-1 (or Tools->Attribute Inspector) and you can set the title there.

I think you may be using a tab-bar, but the process is the same. Click once on the tab bar to select that, THEN click on the specific button you want to change the title for and bring up the Attribute Inspector (cmd-1 or Tools->Attribute Inspector).